# character does not get typed when input has keydown event listener and in debug mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have an input with a keydown event listener.  I'm new at javascript/html so maybe its obvious but when I try it out in the browser every thing works. I type a character and I can see that my javascript ran and then I type another character and it works. But when I open the chrome developer tools and I put a break point in the event listener function then when I type something it does not appear in the input element after the event listener finished running. What is the reason for this?

Here is my javascript:

```
$("#author").keydown(function(event) {

});
```

and here is the html element:

```
<input class="form-control" name="author" type="text" id="author">
```

So to try and explain it again: when I type a character (for example "m") in the input element then the letter "m" shows up in the input element. When I type another character, that one also shows up. Then I refresh the page. I open the chrome developer tools and put a break point on the event listener. I type in my keyboard "m", and the empty event listener runs and there is no indication on the page that I typed "m". It is not showing up in the input element. When I remove the debug point it works. I type a character and it shows up in the input element.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/5285/) is a jsfiddle example. If you type into the input box it works. If you open the dev tools (at least in chrome) you type and continue the js interpreter nothing is typed.

Comment: I think you've hit that scenario where the key was pressed down, you can see what the key is, but the `value` of the input field hasn't been updated to include it yet, so when you test the `length`, you're getting the previous length... and value. Depending on your needs, if you capture the `keypress` event, it will be "after" the key was added.

Comment: yes, its true. But why is it that when the code finishes executing, why doesn't the letter that was typed show up on the page?

Comment: you nee to use keypress to get length of the input field.

Comment: @guyfawkes I think the problem has nothing to do with length. I took out all of the code from the event listener and still when I have the developer tools open with a debug point on the function then when I type a letter on the keyboard, it does not show up in the input element afterwards. When I remove the debug point it works.

Answer (score 1):

With basic typing of a letter, there are several events that actually fire (you can decide which ones you want to listen to)

So if you type the letter "**M**" in a text field you actually fire several events, in the following order:

1. Keydown
2. Keypress
3. Keyup

If you hold down the key, it will repeatedly fire the "down" and "press" events.

```js
$("#author").keydown(function(event){
  var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
 $('#events').append('keydown: ' + key + '<br/>');
});
$("#author").keyup(function(event){
  var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
 $('#events').append('keyup: ' + key + ' value:' + $("#author").val() + '<br/><hr/>');
});
$("#author").keypress(function(event){
 $('#events').append('keypress: value:' + $("#author").val() + '<br/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" name="author" type="text" id="author">
<div id="events"></div>
```

The trick is, that although without the debug tools open, you *SEE* the value entered in the field, it isn't really entered until the keypress event fires.  However if you have a break point set, or never "return" from the keydown event, the press never happens, and the field never updates to include the appended character.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I break the events by calling `event.preventDefault()` in `keydown` event.